# Upgrading script to work with jquery_1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just updated our jquery library from v1.3.2 to 1.7.2, and this is the only script (endless_page.js) is all that's left to fix.  I'm assuming the synstax in this was depreciated or something, but Any help would be much appreciated!!!

```
 var currentPage = 1;
 var path = window.location.pathname;
 var ajax_path;

function checkScroll() {
  if (nearBottomOfPage()) {
    call_ajax();
}  else {
   setTimeout("checkScroll()", 100);
 }
}

function call_ajax() {

    $("#loading-or-more").fadeOut(100, function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<p class="headline" id="loading-or-more" style="display:none;text-align:center;margin-left:20px;"><img src="../../images/newlajaxoader.gif" style="float:left;margin-top:-10px;" > 10 more items on the way</p>');
    $("#loading-or-more").fadeIn(10);
    });
    currentPage ++;
    ajax_path = full_path(currentPage);
    $.ajax({
    url: ajax_path ,
    success: function(data) { 

        if (data=="false") { 
            $("#loading-or-more").replaceWith('<p class="headline" id="end-of-scroll" style="display:none;text-align:center;">  <a href="#"  class="submit gradientBGRed morecategories"> Back to top &uarr;  </a> </p>'); 
            $("#end-of-scroll").fadeIn(10);
            }
        else {
                $(".mb-lot-items").append(data); 
                // $(".ajax-results-list").slideDown('slow');
                checkScroll();                                                  
                $("#loading-or-more").replaceWith('<a  id="loading-or-more" class="headline gradientBGRed morecategories" href="#items-ajax-mobile"><span>More items</span></a>');  }

          } 
    });
}

function nearBottomOfPage() {
  return scrollDistanceFromBottom() < 400;
}

function scrollDistanceFromBottom(argument) {
  return $(document).height() - ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());
}

function full_path(currentPage) {
    return (path+"?page=" + currentPage+"&format=js") ;
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
     // checks if "MORE" exists, if so calls checkscroll
     if ($("#loading-or-more").length) { checkScroll(); }
    });
```

Comment: what errors do you get? Should improve your answer acceptance; `0%` is fairly disrespectful!

Comment: Are there erros in your JS console? If not, what isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I should of put that in my post.  No errors associated to this guy.  Weird, right?

Comment: place `console.log(data)` in the success function. use a web inspector to check the console and see what data outputs. Also, if you use the inspector, you can check the 'NET' panel to see if the ajax call is being made. From this point, you can verify if the params are being sent properly, and are formed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify the datatype to text, and she started getting the data.  Thanks @Ohgodwhy

```
    dataType: "text",
```